# Can this be simplified with key()?

Tags: xml, xslt

The following code work fine but I want to simplify it. In these example I have 11 currency denominations (I have only included four here to simplify the question) and I would like a way to simplify this code in a way I don't have to repeat the line with `thousand or hundred or fifty ... or one` three times. It seems to me it could be done using `<xsl:key` but I haven't found the way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="test">
        <root>
            <other1>
            </other1>
            <currency g="1">
                <sth1>A</sth1>
                <thousand>1</thousand>
                <hundred>2</hundred>
                <fifty>4</fifty>
                <one>10</one>
                <sth2>C</sth2>
            </currency>
            <currency g="2">
                <sth1>A</sth1>
                <sth2>C</sth2>
            </currency>
            <currency g="3">
                <sth1>A</sth1>
                <thousand>1</thousand>
                <hundred>2</hundred>
                <fifty>4</fifty>
                <one>10</one>
                <sth2>C</sth2>
            </currency>
            <other2>
            </other2>
        </root>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" name="curr" select="xalan:nodeset($test)/root"/>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:call-template name="currency"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="currency">
        <xsl:for-each select="$curr/currency[thousand or hundred or fifty or one]">
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 1">
                <xsl:variable name="nextSibling1" select="following-sibling::currency[thousand or hundred or fifty or one][1]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="nextSibling2" select="following-sibling::currency[thousand or hundred or fifty or one][2]"/>
                <col1>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="total"/>
                </col1>
                 <col2>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="$nextSibling1" mode="total"/>
                 </col2>
                 <col3>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="$nextSibling2" mode="total"/>
                 </col3>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="currency" mode="total">
        <xsl:value-of select="thousand*1000 + hundred*100 + fifty*50 + one"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output:

```
<root>
<col1>1410</col1>
<col2>1410</col2>
<col3/>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this exercise in two or three sentences? I don't understand the logic of isolating a group of 3 first, then skipping some of the siblings in that group, potentially reaching into the next group.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Hi Michael, I want to simplify the code so I don't have to repeat ```currency[thousand or hundred or fifty or one]``` three times. In the real code that line is much longer.

Comment: You are repeating what you already said in your original question. That does not answer my question.

Comment: The real code is to generate xml-fo to create a fo-table of three columns. In this case, there are only two currency blocks so they will only occupy the first two columns (in one row) off the three. If there were five blocks, then it will use two rows, the first row will have three values and the second row will have only two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure what exactly your code is supposed to accomplish. If you don't want to repeat the `[thousand or hundred or fifty or one]` predicate, then maybe try something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="test">
        <root>
            <other1>
            </other1>
            <currency g="1">
                <sth1>A</sth1>
                <thousand>1</thousand>
                <hundred>2</hundred>
                <fifty>4</fifty>
                <one>10</one>
                <sth2>C</sth2>
            </currency>
            <currency g="2">
                <sth1>A</sth1>
                <sth2>C</sth2>
            </currency>
            <currency g="3">
                <sth1>A</sth1>
                <thousand>1</thousand>
                <hundred>2</hundred>
                <fifty>4</fifty>
                <one>10</one>
                <sth2>C</sth2>
            </currency>
            <other2>
            </other2>
        </root>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" name="curr" select="xalan:nodeset($test)/root/currency[thousand or hundred or fifty or one]"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="$curr">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <xsl:if test="$i mod 3 = 1">
                    <col1 >
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="total"/>
                    </col1>
                     <col2>
                         <xsl:apply-templates select="$curr[$i + 1]" mode="total"/>
                     </col2>
                     <col3>
                         <xsl:apply-templates select="$curr[$i + 2]" mode="total"/>
                     </col3>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
     <xsl:template match="currency" mode="total">
         <xsl:value-of select="thousand*1000 + hundred*100 + fifty*50 + one"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for this try. It somehow doesn't produce the same result. You can see my output up ^ there. In my example the selected blocks are those identified with g="1" and g="3".

Comment: Sorry, a stupid copy/paste mistake. Try it now.

Comment: ¡Interesting!, I didn't thought of moving that currency selection to the variable itself. That would work. I would need to create several of those variables for other non-currency node. Thanks. I thought defining a key somehow I could achieve that.

Comment: Weird: If I change the ```for-each``` for a template ```<xsl:template match="currency[position() mod 3 = 1]">``` the ```<currency g="2">``` is seen within the template and the result is not what I expected at all. I though g='2' should not exists in ```$curr```.

Comment: The  main thing here is not moving the predicate to the variable but the switch away from preceding sibling. Preceding sibling is evaluated in the context of the input tree, not in the context of your selection. • Keys are used to resolve cross-references - I don't see that you have any here. • As for the template, the position depends on the instruction applying the template.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. ```$curr``` is not really a tree, but fractions of trees (just branches). I cannot do ```$curr/currency[1]``` but ```$curr[1]```.